# What is the correct RoboCopy command for my intended sync job?

Tags: windows, sync, nas, robocopy

I've never used RoboCopy before and I'd like to make sure a particular operation goes smoothly. I've built an OpenMediaVault NAS and I previously copied all my relevant files to it from my Windows 10 installation, but I've since modified some of the local files and I'd like to learn the proper RoboCopy command to do a one-way sync. Basically, I want to only copy new and modified files to the NAS. I'm assuming that I don't need to copy certain file attributes like ACL entries since the NAS has its own ownership tree and whatnot. I'm asking for help because I don't specifically know what certain RoboCopy options do; for example, the **/it** argument includes "tweaked" files, but I don't know what that means. I'm trying to sync from my local **D:** to my network **Z:**, any help would be appreciated! This would be a one-time job before I remove a couple of hard drives from my personal rig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to run the cmd of the following form:

```
robocopy D: Z: /mir /e
```

It supposing that you wish to **mirror** C: to G:.

References:

- [How To Use Robocopy To Transfer Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTzTeHmKMKw)
- [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)
- [is it possible to use RoboCopy to mirro a whole hard drive?](https://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?40281-Is-it-posible-to-use-RoboCopy-to-mirror-a-whole-hard-drive)
- [run robocopy bat to copy entire drive to another drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302049/run-robocopy-bat-to-copy-entire-drive-to-another-drive)
- [How to use Robocopy to back up all your data in Windows 10: Commands and examples](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-back-up-just-your-data-in-windows-10-with-robocopys-multi-threaded-feature/)